# Insert Table header Row when column value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of overdue customer invoices.  Each customer could have several overdue invoices and I want to collate these into separate customer tables, with a sum total of due amount.

I want this to be in one worksheet, with the header row above each customer table.

Therefore, I'm looking for a VBA macro that will go through the data in column A and when it sees a change, from one customer number to the next, it totals up the values for that customer and inserts the header row, ready for the next customer.  And continues on...

[Example sheet Here](https://www.bigskyriders.com/Example.xlsx)

Sheet(tab)1 shows raw data, sheet2 shows how the formatted data should look.

I'm stumped sorry and any help or direction appreciated.  Hope the info is clear.

Answer (score 0):

To get started I suggest you search google "creating vba macros read and write column"
Are you familiar with VBA macro? If not, you could use a combination of index, and match formula.

Otherwise VBA solution logic, in VBA editor - which is accessible by Alt +F11:
Click on the sheet you want your VBA code to apply to and start writing your function. For example a function to check a cell range called "myFunction" would be as follows,

A single example:

```
Sub myFunction ()

If range.("A1").value = "Customer1" then
Range("B1:E1").Insert([Shift], [CopyOrigin])

end If
Sub End
```

More work required to check condition on event, dynamic insert, and will need to be wrapped in a loop. The below are tutorials specific to the job you need to program your macro for.

VBA copy and paste code if condition is met tutorial here : https://youtu.be/qGZQIl9JJk4
VBA insert tutorial here : https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-insert-row/#Excel-VBA-Constructs-to-Insert-Rows
VBA How to SUM Totals At Bottom of a Column Dynamically : https://youtu.be/_0Vcnb3xdOM

Answer (score 0):

```
The first question is-- What VBA have you tried?

Next, change col A heading to Customer, and col E heading to Amount
because these are the desired output headings .
Next, did you know that by dropping down View, and then Macros,
that there is a RECORD button?  Click it.

Finally, it records your pressing Insert / PivotTable  on a New sheet.
Drag the Amount field down to the Values box
After you drag each of the other fields to the Rows box,
 left click on it in the Rows box, and select FieldSettings --
    Subtotals tab -- Automatic for Customer, None for the others
    Layout tab -- Show item labels in tabular form  for each field
      and just for Customer field--Insert page break after each item
At the end, click on any cell of the pivot, select PivotTableOptions --
    Totals&Filters tab -- unclick Column totals

Click PageLayout, 
  then Margins -- make them narrow
  then Sheet -- Rows to print at the top
  Maybe Header -- Custom Header

Finally click on View / Macro
  StopRecording
Presto,  now the VBA has been captured.
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I've tried quite a few macros, but most that I can find are creating new sheets or even workbooks, rather than keeping it on one sheet. I haven't been able to work out how to edit them to do what I need.

Anyway, I'll try this and post back!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so all you have to do is insert a Subtotal.  Check out these screen shots.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Depending on which version of Excel you are using, would probably determine how to navigate to the Subtotal button.  Google for that, if you can't fine it.  Should be super-simple.